# List Files from Templates Directory in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-11

I would like to generate a blog posts overview. For that I want to read the html files from a folder inside the templates folder in the resources folder where Spring Boot stores its templates.

I tried that but it doesnt return an error but also list no files.

What is the way to go here?

Thanks

```
@Controller
public class Route {

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() throws IOException {
        final String path = "templates/blog";
        final Resource res = resourceLoader.getResource("templates/blog");
        try (final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(res.getInputStream()))) {
            reader.lines().forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
        }
        return "blog/a";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
@Controller
public class Route {

    @Value("classpath:templates/blog/*")
    private Resource[] resources;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() throws IOException {
        for (final Resource res : resources) {
            System.out.println(res.getFilename());
        }
        return "blog/a";
    }
}
```

did the trick to me.

Comment: You saved me a day!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this using [NIO2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html).

In order for NIO2 to work, it requires the [concept of FileSystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html), and one can be created from the jar URI. Then this file system can be used with Files/Paths.
The code below contains two branches - the first handles loading the files **from inside Jar**, the second branch - when the code runs **from IDE** or via `"mvn spring-boot:run"`.

All streams are being used via [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) so they will be auto-closed.

The find function starts from the top of the file system and recursively searches for html files.

```
public static void readFile(String location) throws URISyntaxException {
        URI uri = Objects.requireNonNull(ReadFromJar.class.getClassLoader().getResource(location)).toURI();
        if (uri.getScheme().equals("jar")) {  //inside jar
            try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, Collections.emptyMap())) { //build a new FS that represents the jar's contents
                Files.find(fs.getPath("/"), 10, (path, fileAttr) -> // control the search depth (e.g. 10)
                        fileAttr.isRegularFile() //match only files
                                && path.toString().contains("blog") //match only files in paths containing "blog"
                                && path.getFileName().toString().matches(".*\\.html")) // match only html files
                        .forEach(ReadFromJar::printFileContent);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else { //from IDE or spring-boot:run
            final Path path = Paths.get(uri);
            try (DirectoryStream<Path> dirStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path)) {
                dirStream.forEach(ReadFromJar::printFileContent);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printFileContent(final Path file) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Full path: " + file.toAbsolutePath().toString());
            Files.lines(file).forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ya that approach I have tried but try to compile it with maven and run it with java -jar. It will not work anymore, because your approach works only if you run it locally. Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Yep, I've understood what your issue is. I've updated the code to handle jar's using FileSystems

Comment: Thanks for your help but your solution looks quite complex. I have found a "spring" like solution with injection.